# tab can not display completely

Tags: flutter, tabs

when the characters  in my tab are long ,the tab will not display completely,there is some white blur in my tab, and I don't know how to make it display completely.

[this is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZfzT.png)

Comment: I know if I  set  isScrollable is true will settle my problem, but I only have three tabs , so if I set this is true ,I don't know how to set the spacing of tabs to make them look  even well.

Answer (score 0):

to add labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero can solve this